# What's the best Apache Camel routes visual designer?

Tags: apache-camel

So, who could advise some good Apache Camel routes visual designer?

Would like to know also if there's some really good Apache Camel routes visualizer (saw some maven2 camel visualizer, but it produce weird results).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some Maven tooling to generate a visual GraphViz dot diagram
http://camel.apache.org/visualisation.html

It is not a designer, and it requires you to install GraphViz to have the graph generated.

FuseSource is working on a GUI designer for Camel, called FuseSource Rider. Its currently in works and will be GA in Q1 2011. It's entire web based which means you just need a web browser to use it. James Strachan is working on this tooling.

More information about this tooling will be posted on the FuseSource site in due time.
http://fusesource.com/

You can see a screenshot of the tooling at the Camel introduction webinar at
http://fusesource.com/resources/video-archived-webinars/

Comment: FuseSource has released the graphical editor. Its titled: Fuse IDE for Camel and you can find it here: http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-ide-camel

Answer (score 4):

There are two enterprise-ready tools available for Apache Camel - from Talend and from JBoss (former FuseSource). I have written a blog post about this topic:

http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2012/11/23/enterprise-ready-tool-support-for-apache-camel/